# Error while invoking the AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to integrate AWS S3 with Lambda, based on this AWS [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html). When an image is added to S3, it will trigger a Lambda function which will get the image from S3, resize it and upload the same to S3 back again.

After copying the function to the AWS Lambda Management, I do get the below message. I am not sure how to handle it. I am using Node.js 8.10 as the runtime. The complete code can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html#with-s3-example-create-function). The file name is index.js, the Lambda handler is index.handler and exports.handler is defined in the Lambda function.

[image]

Upon saving the Lambda function and triggering the same by putting an image in S3, I do get the below message in the CloudWatch Logs.

[image]

I am not familiar with Node.js and am stuck here. Any solution would be appreciated.

**Update:** Here is the folder structure or the tree.

[image]

Comment: at first glance it seems an issue with the file name, can you provide your `tree`?

Comment: @Federkun I have updated the OP with the tree. It looks good, there is something else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not deployed the Lambda function correctly. This code has dependencies on the GraphicsMagick and Async libraries, and you have not uploaded either of them to Lambda so your `require()` calls are failing. You should re-read the [Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html#with-s3-example-create-function), but basically you need to:

- npm init
- npm install gm async --save
- zip -r function.zip .
- aws lambda create-function ... (per the tutorial)

Your deployed Lambda function should look like this (note the inclusion of a package.json file as well as node_modules subfolders for the dependent NPM packages):

[image]